# Python: Importing a file from a parent folder

Tags: python

...Now I know this question has been asked many times & I have looked at these other threads. Nothing so far has worked, from using `sys.path.append('.')` to just import `foo`.

I have a python file that wishes to import a file (that is in its parent directory). Can you help me figure out how my child file can successfully import its a file in its parent directory. I am using python 2.7.

The structure is like so (each directory also has the `__init__.py` file in it):

```
StockTracker/  
└─ Comp/  
   ├─ a.py  
   └─ SubComp/  
      └─ b.py
```

Inside b.py, I would like to import `a.py`: So I have tried each of the following but I still get an error inside `b.py` saying `"There is no such module a"`.

```py
import a

import .a

import Comp.a

import StockTracker.Comp.a

import os
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
import a    
sys.path.remove('.')
```

Comment: How do you invoke python? That is, how does it find StockTracker.Comp.SubComp.b?

Answer (score 15):

```
from .. import a
```

Should do it. This will only work on recent versions of Python--from 2.6, I believe [Edit: since 2.5].

Each level (Comp and Subcomp) must also be have an `__init__.py` file for this to work. You've said that they do.

Comment: I believe it is since 2.7. It's your answer, Could you check?

Comment: Well, we're both wrong! It's since 2.5. Thanks, I'll update it.

Comment: That probably works. But also: Please don't. Make sure the absolute import works instead.

Comment: @Lennart: Why? This is precisely the situation relative imports are designed for, and you might not want to expose the subpackage to all imports via PYTHONPATH. The only argument I can see against using a relative import is backwards compatibility, and supporting Python 2.4 would hardly be my top priority.

Comment: The current module are apparently exposed for import, so why not "expose" the package properly instead. And you wouldn't need to do any PYTHONPATH hacks if things are properly installed, and if it is, absolute import will work.

Comment: @Lennart: I agree that the package should be on the PYTHONPATH, if only from the location of the scripts calling it. But, if you develop something complex and then rename the top level package, you'd have to go through replacing lots of import statements. Relative imports are there for just this situation, and there's nothing wrong with using them.

Comment: Pfah, search and replace is a trivial procedure. With absolute imports you know where they come from, less naming confusion.

Comment: @Lennart: Well, you know where the relative form comes from: look for "a" one package level above the current script.

Comment: Which means you need to look at the file path to figure out which `a` package it is, out of several. This is fine if you only have one `a.py` in the whole package. If, however, you have a module package called `a.py`, a view called `a.py` and portlet called `a.py` and a set of adapters called `a.py`, it's going to be pretty damn confusing.  But I don't think this is gonna convince you either, so we'll just have to disagree. I don't really see a practical usecase for .. imports, they are only going to be confusing.

Comment: @ThomasK how to import a file from b.py if its present in sub folder of Comp folder ?

Answer (score 10):

> When packages are structured into
>   subpackages (as with the sound package
>   in the example), you can use absolute
>   imports to refer to submodules of
>   siblings packages. For example, if the
>   module sound.filters.vocoder needs to
>   use the echo module in the
>   sound.effects package, it can use from
>   sound.effects import echo.
>
> Starting with Python 2.5, in addition
>   to the implicit relative imports
>   described above, you can write
>   explicit relative imports with the
>   from module import name form of import
>   statement. These explicit relative
>   imports use leading dots to indicate
>   the current and parent packages
>   involved in the relative import. From
>   the surround module for example, you
>   might use:
>
> ```
> from . import echo
> from .. import formats
> from ..filters import equalizer
> ```

Quote from here http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Answer (score 7):

If the Comp directory is in your PYTHONPATH environment variable, plain old

```
import a
```

will work.

If you're using Linux or OS X, and launching your program from the bash shell, you can accomplish that by

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/Comp
```

For Windows, take a look at these links:

- http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html
- http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html

EDIT:

To modify the path programmatically, you were on the right track in your original question. You just need to add the parent directory instead of the current directory.

```
sys.path.append("..")
import a
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have never heard of the  PYTHONPATH environment variable? Would you be able to ellaborate how I would do what your saying? Inside the directory StockTracker, I have the main program initiator file called RunStockTracker.py, should I "make sure the Comp directory is in your PYTHONPATH environment variable" (in code) in this file?

Comment: This answer (`sys.path.append('..')`) is the only one that will work, if you are running `b.py` as [`__main__`, i.e. the top-level script environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)