# importing an attribute from parent directory

Tags: python, flask, import

This is how my folder and files looks like:

```
/app
    __init__.py
    /admin
        __init__.py
        models.py
```

and `app/__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app.admin.models import *


app = Flask('app')  

@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def show_users():
    return "list of all Users:\n" + User.query.limit(5).all()
```

and `app/admin/models.py` :

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import app


db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    pass
```

I want have access to my `User` model in `init` file,from [Import from parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636976/python-importing-a-file-from-a-parent-folder) and [import script from a parenet directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951255/import-script-from-a-parent-directory) I have tried `from app import *` or `from .. import app` or also put `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` in `__init__` file and import it in `models.py` with  `from app import db` or `from .. import db` but I'm keep getting `app` and `db` are not defined and also I think it's weird that I should import both file in each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is about Flask extensions, while your app created sqlalchemy extension didn't initialize, therefore it cause error. The best practice is to keep extensions initializes in same place:

```
#app/__init__.py
...
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from app.admin.models import *

#app/admin/models.py
...
from app import db
```

If you do this changes, it will work.

Comment: I have same issue yet : `can not import name db`

Comment: The model import  should be after extension initialize `db=SQLAlchemy(app)` `from app.admin.models import *`

Comment: Now it works! but why db definition should be before importing models?

Comment: Because in model.py file you trying to use db but not defined yet.